# how to convert jquery codes to Vue js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, vue.js

working with Laravel 5 and I have following bootstrap toggle button

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="menu-toggle">Toggle Menu</button>

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
```

and my jquery code is

```
<script>
$("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
});
</script>
```

then how could I write above jquery codes in vue js to compatible with above toggle button

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a data attribute called `isMenuVisible`, initialised to **false**.
2. Add a click listener to the button that toggles the value of `isMenuVisible` between **true** and **false**: `@click="isMenuVisible = !isMenuVisible`.
3. Conditionally apply a class that hides the menu when `isMenuVisible` is **false**.
   `:class="{ 'hide': !isMenuVisible }"`

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="isMenuVisible = !isMenuVisible">Toggle Menu</button>
    <div class="menu" :class="{ 'hide': !isMenuVisible }">...</div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      isMenuVisible: false
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: @ranawaka please explain what is not working. Did you installed Vue somehow (CDN, npm)? Do you have an error?